# Excel looping problems macro FindNext

Tags: excel, vba

When I'm searching for mCell it just run with first value and not loop for other value so what should I can do?.

```
 Sub finddataver2()

 Dim mRange As Range
 Dim mFCell As String
 Dim mCell As Range
 Dim mName As String

 Dim sRange As Range
 Dim sFCell As String
 Dim sCell As Range
 Dim seg As String

 Dim neg As String

 Dim i As Integer
 Dim finalrow As Integer

 neg = Sheets("FindSupp").Range("C2").Value
 mName = Sheets("FindSupp").Range("C4").Value
 seg = Sheets("FindSupp").Range("C6").Value

 Sheets("FindSupp").Range("B14:L2000").ClearContents
 Worksheets("Data").Select

 finalrow = Sheets("Data").Range("A10000").End(xlUp).row

 Worksheets("Data").Select
 Set mRange = Sheets("Data").Range("I:I")
 Set mCell = mRange.Find(What:=mName, MatchCase:=False, LookAt:=xlPart)
 Worksheets("Data").Select
 Set sRange = Sheets("Data").Range("H:H")
 Set sCell = sRange.Find(What:=seg, MatchCase:=False, LookAt:=xlPart)

 Worksheets("Data").Select
 For i = 2 To finalrow

     If neg = "All" Or neg = "" Then
```

The problems start here when im serach for value it do not loop only take for the first value only of mCell

```
         If mName = "" Or mName = "All" Then

             If seg = "" Or seg = "All" Then
                 Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 11)).Copy
                 Sheets("FindSupp").Range("B1000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, ).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
             ElseIf Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 8) = sCell.Value Then
                 sFCell = sCell.Address
                 Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 11)).Copy
                 Sheets("FindSupp").Range("B1000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
                 Set sCell = sRange.FindNext(sCell)
             End If


         ElseIf Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 9) = mCell.Value Then

             If seg = "" Or seg = "All" Then
                 Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 11)).Copy
                 Sheets("FindSupp").Range("B1000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats

             ElseIf Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 8) = sCell.Value Then
                 sFCell = sCell.Address
                 Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 11)).Copy
                 Sheets("FindSupp").Range("B1000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
                 Set sCell = sRange.FindNext(sCell)

             End If

         End If

     ElseIf Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 2) = neg Then

         If mName = "" Or mName = "All" Then

             If seg = "" Or seg = "All" Then
                 Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 11)).Copy
                 Sheets("FindSupp").Range("B1000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats

             ElseIf Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 8) = sCell.Value Then
                 sFCell = sCell.Address
                 Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 11)).Copy
                 Sheets("FindSupp").Range("B1000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
                 Set sCell = sRange.FindNext(sCell)
             End If


         ElseIf Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 9) = mCell.Value Then

             If seg = "" Or seg = "All" Then

                 Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 11)).Copy
                 Sheets("FindSupp").Range("B1000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
                 Set mCell = mRange.FindNext(mCell)

             ElseIf Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 8) = sCell.Value Then
                 sFCell = sCell.Address
                 Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 11)).Copy
                 Sheets("FindSupp").Range("B1000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats

             End If

         End If

     End If

 Next i

 Worksheets("FindSupp").Select
 Cells(2, 3).Select
 Worksheets("FindSupp").Range("Z:Z").ClearContents

 End Sub
```

To make question more simple how can i loop this thing....

```
    ElseIf Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 9) = mFCell Then

    If seg = "" Or seg = "All" Then
        Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 11)).Copy
        Sheets("FindSupp").Range("B1000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
        Set mCell = mRange.FindNext(mCell)
```

Actually, I found the problems where it is but the problems is I don't know how to make it loop

```
 Worksheets("Data").Select
 Set mRange = Sheets("Data").Range("I:I")
 Set mCell = mRange.Find(What:=mName, MatchCase:=False, LookAt:=xlPart)
 Worksheets("Data").Select
 Set sRange = Sheets("Data").Range("H:H")
 Set sCell = sRange.Find(What:=seg, MatchCase:=False, LookAt:=xlPart)
```

Comment: Please fix your formatting

Comment: It may be dumb to ask, but what do you actually set Finalrow to be?

`finalrow = Sheets("Data").Range("A10000").End(xlUp).row`

Comment: Actually the finalrow can be infinite but i have capped the value to 10000 rows of data. So loop will go until the finalrow. Its use for loop condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're attacking your problem in a rather awkward way. There are some errors in your code (too many to list if I'm brutally honest), but I'd like to propose a different search structure to you.

If I've read your post correctly you want to retrieve rows of data when three conditions are met (neg, seg and m). Those conditions are true if either the user has selected 'All' or the search item matches its respective data item.

To achieve this you simply need to store *skip* flags if 'All' is picked and then move to the next row if any of the other conditions are false.

The code below shows you a way of doing that. A few points to note:

1. Read the large data set into an array, as it's far quicker to manipulate.
2. I've created a little `Type` structure to keep the code neater. This is really just a holder for a group of related variables. You simply define it at the top of your module (above any `Subs` or `Functions`).
3. There's no need to copy/paste row by row. If you must paste (rather than write an array straight to the output worksheet), then it's quicker to define the target range and copy/paste it all in one go.
4. Your *PasteType* `xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats` looks odd - just make sure you know exactly what that's doing.
5. You'll see from the code that there's very little need to `Select` sheets or cells in VBA.

Here's the code - you could paste the whole lot into a `Module`:

```
Option Explicit
Private Type SearchItems
    Value As String
    Skip As Boolean
    Index As Integer
End Type
Public Sub FindData()
    Dim item(2) As SearchItems
    Dim suppWs As Worksheet
    Dim dataWs As Worksheet
    Dim found As Boolean
    Dim data As Variant
    Dim hits As Range
    Dim r As Long
    Dim i As Integer

    'Find the boundaries of your data however you wish
    'I'm using a quick, but dirty, UsedRange object.
    'Read data into an array
    Set dataWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
    data = dataWs.UsedRange.Value2

    'Set search item parameters
    Set suppWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("FindSupp")
    With item(0)
        .Index = 2
        .Value = suppWs.Range("C2").Value2
        .Skip = (Len(.Value) = 0) Or (UCase(.Value) = "ALL")
    End With
    With item(1)
        .Index = 9
        .Value = suppWs.Range("C4").Value2
        .Skip = (Len(.Value) = 0) Or (UCase(.Value) = "ALL")
    End With
    With item(2)
        .Index = 8
        .Value = suppWs.Range("C6").Value2
        .Skip = (Len(.Value) = 0) Or (UCase(.Value) = "ALL")
    End With

    'Loop through the data to find the compound matches
    For r = 2 To UBound(data, 1)
        found = True
        For i = 0 To 2
            With item(i)
                If Not .Skip Then found = (data(r, .Index) = .Value)
            End With
            If Not found Then Exit For
        Next
        'Add the row to our range if all conditions are met
        If found Then Set hits = SafeUnion(hits, dataWs.Cells(r, 1).Resize(, 11))
    Next

    'Do whatever you like with the found rows
    'Your PasteSpecial PasteType is unusual but I've kept it here
    If Not hits Is Nothing Then
        hits.Copy
        suppWs.Range("B14").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
    End If

End Sub
Private Function SafeUnion(rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range) As Range
    If rng1 Is Nothing Then
        Set SafeUnion = rng2
    Else
        Set SafeUnion = Union(rng1, rng2)
    End If
End Function
```

Update

Use this line if you need to check if the value is contained within the cell:

```
                If Not .Skip Then found = (InStr(data(r, .Index), .Value) > 0)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot and the algorithm quite find fast than mine.

Comment: But my search 'seg' and 'm' are search word in one cell and then it will go next.
Means that, if i want search bread in cell that the cell contain ' rice, bread , water '  it will search the bread and it will copy and go next

Comment: So for each search item, you want to check whether the cell contains that item? If so, see my edit.

Comment: Just a simple update and it founded. How worse I'm in excel macro I need learn more.
However, Thanks3 a lot @ambie, I hope I can learn with this site though all members

Comment: Glad this site produced the answer you needed. If I could give you some advice, be much more specific when you phrase your questions. I had to do a lot of guess work, trying to work out what you were attempting to do and you missed a key piece of information, ie that you wanted to check if a cell contained text rather than was equal to a value. Good luck with your VBA journey.

Comment: Thanks @Ambie I hope your will be a successful person in life and hereafter